# Memory addressing with a variable for the (1,2,4,8) size

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a function where I'd like to pass it the starting address of a list/array as well as the element size and it to return the size. Something like, in pseudo-code:

```
int size(*start_addr, int (1,2,4 or 8) elem_size)
```

And in assembly to be able to run a loop that contains the following instruction:

```
mov (%edi, %eax, 4), %r8d
```

However, I want to be able to use the `elem_size` instead of the hardcoded `4`. is it possible to pass a register such as:

```
mov (%edi, %eax, " value in %esi "), %r8d
```

If not, what might be the best way to get around this? (I was thinking about passing it an offset with the `size * index` offset as another register and removing the 1/2/4/8 `size` part).

Comment: Do the address math separately, with integer instructions like `imul %esi, %eax`; look at compiler output for an example.  The scale is encoded as a 2-bit shift count in the machine code; there aren't any bits that can signal that it's a register, or even enough room to encode a 3-bit register number.  And of course that would require the CPU to have a multiplier in its AGUs, or some kind of bit-scan and shift even if it's restricted to a power of 2, which is not a plausible hardware design.

Comment: `%r8d` is a 4-byte register.  How are you planning to handle different operand-sizes, separate from the address-calculation problem?  That's also hard-coded into the machine code and can't be made variable.  (For looping over an array, you just use ptr += size instead of redoing scaling every iteration; that's easy.)

Comment: `bsf %rsi, %rcx` `shl %cl, %rax` then use `mov (%rdi, %rax), %r8/%r8d/%r8w/%r8b`. My question is, for the `mov` instruction you need to specify the register size (`%r8/%r8d/%r8w/%r8b`, the size is always hardcoded. Why did you bother about your question?

Comment: @W.Chang sorry I don't understand most of your comment. I'm pretty new to assembly -- for example, what is `bsf`, and why the `shl` instruction?

Comment: @carl.hiass - `bsf` scan for the first least significant non-zero bit and return its position. so `rcx` becomes `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` when `rsi` is `1`, `2`, `4` and `8` respectively. `shl` left shifts the target operand `%cl` times, which essentially means multiply it by 2 `%cl` times. But, again, I don't think it is necessary. As Peter commented, "you just use ptr += size". Show us your actual codes and we may able to help you better.

Comment: @W.Chang: On modern x86, `imul` is faster than BSF + SHL.  BSF has the same performance as IMUL on Intel (1 uop that can only run on port 1, 3 cycle latency).  Variable-count SHL is 3 uops on Intel (because of possible FLAGS preserving if the count was zero). AMD has fast SHL, but slow BSF (although you can use REP BSF so it decodes as TZCNT on CPUs that support it.)  Still, on Sandybridge-family or Zen, SHL is only good if you have the caller pass a shift count instead of a scale factor.  But then you couldn't do `ptr += size` with just an add like a normal person.

Comment: @carl.hiass: I was going to post my comments as an answer, but I don't know what to say about the load instruction.  You can't parameterize the operand-size to make a loop that can increment elements of different sizes.  (At least not anything close to efficiently).  What exactly are you really trying to do in a loop?

Comment: @Peter Cordes - I honestly didn't understand the purpose of the question. To me using either `(%edi, %eax, 4)` or `ptr += size` is way better. Anyway, the reason that I used `BSF` &`SHL` was because @carl.hiass mentioned running a loop. In that case, `BSF` only needs to run once, and `SHL` is faster than `IMUL` at least on AMD CPUs (1 μop, 0.5 cycle latency). I really don't know why Intel cannot make `SHL` be as fast as AMD, while they can make `IMUL` so amazingly fast.

Comment: @W.Chang: Oh I see, yes a loop hoisting BSF makes sense if you need random access so can't ptr+=size.  Intel can execute fast shifts, but only without FLAGS updates (BMI2 `shlx`).  I don't know how AMD manages to handle the case of cl=0 meaning FLAGS have to be unchanged without a false dependency or extra merging uop or anything.  Intel P6-family (before Sandybridge) used to handle `shl reg, cl` as a single uop but would stall the front-end until the shift *retired* if it encountered a later instruction that read FLAGS written by the shift!  (See [this Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/q/36510095))